# Velocity of a boat after getting off of it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, velocity

> A 50 kg person gets off of a 100 kg boat at rest with a velocity of 10 m/s. What will be the velocity of the boat in the opposite direction?

Apparently, the momentum of the person and the boat are equal in magnitude, and we can solve for the velocity of the boat from there, but I don't get why they're equal?

Answer (score 2):

> Apparently, the momentum of the person and the boat are equal in
> magnitude, and we can solve for the velocity of the boat from there,
> but I don't get why they're equal?

The law of conservation of momentum states that the momentum of an isolated system is a constant. An isolated system is one that is not subjected to external forces that can alter the momentum of the system.

The horizontal momentum of the boat/person system is conserved provided there are no net external horizontal forces acting on the system. That means the horizontal force between the water and the boat (fluid friction) needs to be negligible. In my opinion, that should have been included in the problem statement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure they are equal. That depends on how you interpret "a 100 kg boat"; is that including (1) or excluding (2) the 50 kg person?

You are correct about the conservation of momentum, so the total momentum must be zero.

In case (1), the boat is now 50 kg so it has a velocity of 10 m/s.
In case (2), the boat is twice as heavy as the person, so it has a velocity of 5 m/s.

Answer (score 0):

**Momentum is conserved** if there are no external forces acting on the system. Internal forces by the Newton's third law cancel and produce no change in the momentum. When person is at rest on the boat, there are gravitational force and buoyancy acting on the boat. Since they cancel out, the net external force acting on the boat-person system is zero, which means momentum is conserved.

Remember that the momentum is a vector quantity - it has both magnitude and direction

$$\vec p = m \vec v$$

Initially, both boat and person are at rest which means total momentum of the **boat-person system** is $0 \text{ kg m/s}$. If person now leaves the boat at $10 \text{ m/s}$ it gains $500 \text{ kg m/s}$ of momentum. For total system momentum to remain $0 \text{ kg m/s}$ the boat's momentum has to be $-500 \text{ kg m/s}$ which translates to $-5 \text{ m/s}$ boat velocity.

Once person gets off the boat, the boat will move at $5 \text{ m/s}$ in the opposite direction. As it moves, there is a drag exerted by the water on the boat which will eventually slow the boat down.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's 3rd law is at play here.

Momentum is exchanged between the two objects, and however much is added to one body needs to be removed from another body. If you remember momentum is force multiplied by time, and Newton's 3rd law has two equal but opposite forces acting on two bodies. Over the same period, these forces describe the same amount of momentum on the two bodies, one added and the other removed.

You can see that the total momentum is conserved here.